# How to properly transfer XMR in monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringsize

Usually I use the following command to transfer XMR:

```
transfer normal 11 <address> <amount>
```

But now I see people are using just:

```
transfer <address> <amount>
```

They don't specify fee and ring size.

What is the default ring size and priority for the second command? And what command should I use?

Comment: At the moment of writing, the ring size is set by default by 11. There's no need to set it. The fee is calculated on specific parameters (such as "random outputs" chosen randomly).

Answer (score 1):

> How to properly transfer XMR in monero-wallet-cli?

```
help transfer
Command usage: 
  transfer [index=<N1>[,<N2>,...]] [<priority>] [<ring_size>] (<URI> | <address> <amount>) [<payment_id>]

Command description: 
  Transfer <amount> to <address>. If the parameter "index=<N1>[,<N2>,...]" is specified, the wallet uses outputs received by addresses of those indices. If omitted, the wallet randomly chooses address indices to be used. In any case, it tries its best not to combine outputs across multiple addresses. <priority> is the priority of the transaction. The higher the priority, the higher the transaction fee. Valid values in priority order (from lowest to highest) are: unimportant, normal, elevated, priority. If omitted, the default value (see the command "set priority") is used. <ring_size> is the number of inputs to include for untraceability. Multiple payments can be made at once by adding URI_2 or <address_2> <amount_2> etcetera (before the payment ID, if it's included)
```

> Usually I use the following command to transfer XMR...

You do not need to specify the optional parameters (the ones enclosed in `[]` from the help).

> What is the default ring size and priority for the second command?

Ring size is currently 11. You actually can't use anything other than 11 as all Monero transactions now use the same fixed ring size.

Priority is `normal` unless you changed the default wallet setting or specify explicitly in `transfer ...`

> And what command should I use?

`transfer <address> <amount>` is the simplest and uses sensible defaults.